# Transfer Limit on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Question: Does Firebase Hosting have a transfer limit of 1000 GB (host)?

in the blaze plan calculator it only allows you to reach 1000gb+ transferred, and I wanted to increase it a little more. Does the Blaze plan allow you to exceed the calculator limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is only in the calculator, there is no such limit on the actual transfer of Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Nice, thank you for clarifying so quickly